# Job failed error when I try to run an excel test script on Botium v1.7.5

Tags: chat, bots

I recently deployed Botium v1.7.5 and have been getting "Job failed: Error: Worker finished with error" error. The bot does not detect any user utterance at all and ends the test session with a fail.

I included screenshots of my [test case settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFSTu.jpg), [test result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxHFH.jpg) and [excel sheet containing test cases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eavds.jpg)

I created a test set from manually chatting with my bot, through a feature in Botium, ran it, and it passed.

Comment: setup is fine. pls enable logging (see botium wiki, troubleshooting) and see what you got, or post log output from docker container

Comment: Hi Florian, this is log file from the console when I try to run the test case: https://mega.nz/#!i0kRVKKL!nA0-2LZHJ5ME39WOXDvQCh2Qpof3oX-p8wuHfBit83A

Comment: no idea what's the problem. pls try to disable the "Chatbot Hyperlink Existance Asserter" in Settings/Registered Components" by unchecking the "Include in Default Component Set" option. upgrade to 1.8 to see more error output in such cases.

Comment: I tried updating it as instructed in the documentation (https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-box-basic-dist) and I'm still on v1.7.5 not 1.8. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: And disabling the "Chatbot Hyperlink Existance Asserter" did not work either

Comment: Updated update instructions - it was not clear that you have to update the git repository first.

Comment: In case you are using the community edition, adding a "RESOURCESDIR" environment variable in docker-compose.yml could also help (setting it to "./resources").